Issues with Ethers Utiility fuction
I built a smart contract and I am trying to test it.
It successfully deploys but not all function works(event emmitter trigger problems) , for example the issueCertificate fuction.
I had to write a debug script to test where the issue is from and then i figured it was from the ethers.utility.id method, i even went further to explicity test the utils Id.
I get this error from my debug.js when i run npx hardhat run scripts/debug.js
Error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at main (/Users/MASTERS/ACV/scripts/debug.js:22:38)


I get this error from my testUtilsId.js when i run node scripts/testUtilsId.js
Error:
(base) ACV % node scripts/testUtilsId.js     

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at testUtilsId (/Users/MASTERS/ACV/scripts/testUtilsId.js:6:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/MASTERS/ACV/scripts/testUtilsId.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

Below is the code of the smartcontract.sol, the debug.js and the testUtilsId.js
CertificateManagement.sol:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract CertificateManagement {
    // Struct to store certificate information
    struct Certificate {
        uint256 id;
        string studentName;
        string course;
        uint256 issueDate;
        bool isValid;
        string issuer;
    }

    // Mapping from certificate ID to certificate details
    mapping(uint256 => Certificate) public certificates;
    // Mapping from an address to a boolean indicating if it is authorized to issue and revoke certificates
    mapping(address => bool) public authorizedIssuers;
    // Event emitted when a certificate is issued
    event CertificateIssued(uint256 indexed certificateID, string studentName, string issuer);
    // Event emitted when a certificate is revoked
    event CertificateRevoked(uint256 indexed certificateID);

    // Modifier to check if the caller is an authorized issuer
    modifier onlyAuthorized() {
        require(authorizedIssuers[msg.sender], "Caller is not authorized");
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        // The deployer of the contract is the initial authorized issuer
        authorizedIssuers[msg.sender] = true;
    }

    // Function to authorize a new issuer
    function addIssuer(address issuer) external onlyAuthorized {
        authorizedIssuers[issuer] = true;
    }

    // Function to revoke issuer rights
    function removeIssuer(address issuer) external onlyAuthorized {
        authorizedIssuers[issuer] = false;
    }

    // Function to issue a new certificate
    function issueCertificate(string memory studentName, string memory course, string memory issuer) public onlyAuthorized returns (uint256) {
        uint256 newCertificateID = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, msg.sender, studentName, course)));
        certificates[newCertificateID] = Certificate(newCertificateID, studentName, course, block.timestamp, true, issuer);
        emit CertificateIssued(newCertificateID, studentName, issuer); // Ensure this line is correct
        return newCertificateID;
    }

    // Function to revoke a certificate
    function revokeCertificate(uint256 certificateID) public onlyAuthorized {
        require(certificates[certificateID].isValid, "Certificate already revoked");
        certificates[certificateID].isValid = false;
        emit CertificateRevoked(certificateID);
    }

    // Function to verify the validity of a certificate
    function verifyCertificate(uint256 certificateID) public view returns (bool) {
        return certificates[certificateID].isValid;
    }
}


debug.js:

require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const utils = ethers.utils;

async function main() {
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const CertificateManagement = await ethers.getContractFactory("CertificateManagement");
    const certManagement = await CertificateManagement.deploy();
    await certManagement.waitForDeployment();
    console.log("CertificateManagement deployed to:", await certManagement.getAddress());

    await certManagement.addIssuer(deployer.address);

    const tx = await certManagement.issueCertificate("John Doe", "Blockchain 101", "University");
    const receipt = await tx.wait();
    console.log("Transaction Receipt:", receipt);

    const logs = receipt.logs;
    console.log("Transaction Logs:", logs);

    if (logs.length > 0) {
        // Calculate the event signature
        const eventSignature = utils.id("CertificateIssued(uint256,string,string)");
        console.log("Event Signature:", eventSignature);
        
        // Log each topic and data for inspection
        logs.forEach((log, index) => {
            console.log(`Log ${index} Address:`, log.address);
            console.log(`Log ${index} Topics:`, log.topics);
            console.log(`Log ${index} Data:`, log.data);
        });

        // Find the log corresponding to the event
        const event = logs.find(log => log.topics[0] === eventSignature);
        if (event) {
            console.log("Event found:", event);
            // The first topic is the event signature, and the second topic is the indexed parameter (certificateID)
            const certificateID = event.topics[1];
            
            // Decode the data part (non-indexed parameters: studentName and issuer)
            const decodedData = utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(
                ["string", "string"],
                event.data
            );
            const studentName = decodedData[0];
            const issuer = decodedData[1];
            
            console.log("Issued Certificate ID:", certificateID);
            console.log("Student Name:", studentName);
            console.log("Issuer:", issuer);
        } else {
            console.log("CertificateIssued event not found in the transaction receipt.");
        }
    } else {
        console.log("No logs found in the transaction receipt.");
    }
}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
});


testUtilsId.js:
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function testUtilsId() {
    // Random string
    const randomString = "Hello World";
    const randomStringHash = ethers.utils.id(randomString);
    console.log(`Hash of "${randomString}": ${randomStringHash}`);

    // Event signature
    const eventSignatureString = "CertificateIssued(uint256,string,string)";
    const eventSignatureHash = ethers.utils.id(eventSignatureString);
    console.log(`Hash of "${eventSignatureString}": ${eventSignatureHash}`);
}

testUtilsId().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
});



ethers.utils - is undefined. do console.log(ethers ) and look what is it.

If I looked at the package documentation correctly, then the import should be without destructuring const ethers = require("hardhat");

I fixed it, found out that the way i made the call was deprecated for v6,
So i changed ethers.utils.id(randomString); to ethers.id(randomString);

I fixed it, found out that the way i made the call was deprecated for v6, So i changed ethers.utils.id(randomString); to ethers.id(randomString);
Basically there is no need to go through the util  subclass.
Here is my updated code for the test script:
const { id } = require("ethers");

async function testUtilsId() {
    // Random string
    const randomString = "Hello World";
    const randomStringHash = id(randomString);
    console.log(`Hash of "${randomString}": ${randomStringHash}`);

    // Event signature
    const eventSignatureString = "CertificateIssued(uint256,string,string)";
    const eventSignatureHash =id(eventSignatureString);
    console.log(`Hash of "${eventSignatureString}": ${eventSignatureHash}`);
}

testUtilsId).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
});



